# Creating a GoDaddy wildcard certificate

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, certificate, wildcard

I have to replace a certificate with a wildcard certificate and I am unsure of the process that I need to take to do this - I have Googled this but I can't find anything particularly straightforward, I apologise if this has been asked already, can someone help?

I think I need to create a keystore file or something like that, do I also need a bundle called gd_bundle.crt to run against on the server? This is pretty confusing for me.

I have been told that the files are in a folder that I need, but not WHICH files I need, the files available are:

```
wildcard.domain.org.crt
wildcard.domain.org.csr
wildcard.domain.org.key
wildcard.domain.org.p12
```

There is also a gd_bundle.crt file in the folder but it's older than these files so I'm not sure I need it.

'domain' replaces the company domain I have.

Our service provider is GoDaddy. The webserver is Apache2 on ubuntu 12.04, using openSSL, the purpose of the certificate is for a web page that displays build snapshots of code for our engineers.

All help and comments are hugely appreciated!

Comment: If you have the above files already, and the files actually contain the bits in the standard formats, then you already have a certificate in to two different formats.  You seem to think you need some other format, but you haven't told us what format you need or or the software/service you need the keys for.  Please edit the question to tell use the type of server, the name of the specific software you are trying to setup and so on.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for replying - I've updated the question to have more detail and hopefully make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had been given the wrong files. The certificate had already been created, for the most part. After I figured out the steps I created a how-to:

1. First you will need to request a wildcard certificate from GoDaddy - please see: GoDaddy SSL certificates
2. Once you have the files you need, you will need to copy them over to the server you want to install / replace the certificate on; copy them to /home/ubuntu/
3. cd into /home/ubuntu/
4. You should have three files, you will need to move them to the correct directories:

   ```
   wildcard.domain.com.crt - move to /etc/ssl/certs/
   wildcard.domain.com.key - move to /etc/ssl/private/
   gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt - move to /usr/share/ca-certificates/
   ```
5. Now you've moved the files to where they need to be, you can install the certificate:
6. Run: sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates - this will convert the gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt to gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem
7. Ensure that gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt is selected
8. Next, type sudo su to log into the root user.
9. cd into /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
10. With the text editor of your choice, edit the configuration file for the site.
11. Find the following three lines and make sure that the file paths correspond with where you moved the files to in step 4:

    ```
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.domain.com.crt8. 
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wildcard.domain.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/gd_bundle-g2-g1.pem - You need to change the filetype from .crt to .pem - if you do not do this, the next step will not work.
    ```
12. Go to a browser, and type https:// [server].domain.com - replace [server] with the name of the server you're working on.
13. Click the little lock icon next to the URL in the address bar
14. Click the connection tab > Certificate Information
15. Check the title and expiry date - it should say *.domain.com. and have the expiry date of the current certificate.
16. Next, run: service apache2 reload. This should run with no errors. If you have any errors, please go back over the previous steps and check you have done everything correctly.
17. Finally, to check that your certificate is installed correctly, repeat the previous five steps. This time, your certificate expiry date should be set to correct future date as per your new certificate.

Hope this helps someone else :)

Answer (score 3):

First figure out if your `wildcard.domain.org.key` is encrypted or not.  For apache to start/restart automatically it must be decrypted.  You can can view it with your favorite text editor/viewer.

The encrypted key would have a first like like this.

```
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The unencrypted key would have a first line like this.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Use a command like this to convert an encrypted key to be unencrypted.  `openssl rsa -in filename.pem -out filename.key`

If this was my system I would copy install the files into `/etc/apache2/ssl` folder and name them like below.  (I prepend the creation date of the key/cert to give me a hint about the age of the cert.  Plus I can upload a new cert early without breaking things if apache needs to be restart before I am ready to use the new cert.)

```
/etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.wildcard.domain.org.key
/etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.wildcard.domain.org.crt
/etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.gd_bundle.crt
```

Then depending on your virtual host config you will need to add lines like this to Apache.

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.wildcard.domain.org.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.wildcard.domain.org.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/YYYYMM.gd_bundle.crt
```

See the [apache mod_ssl docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html) for more details about how to configure Apache.